# karate robot linux - not found images locators

Tags: karate

I am trying to automate an RDP desktop in Linux with karate robot, I managed to get it to recognize the windows by downloading the wmctrl dependency, but it does not recognize the images or rather it does not find them, does anyone know why this is?

I tried trying to compile the open cv library in java with cmake but I didn't have positive results, maybe I was missing a step or something.

Comment: I doubt if you will get any support on this, my suggestion do try and dig through the code and contribute, most teams use this on windows

Comment: Hello Mr. Peter Thomas, a pleasure to speak with you, by any chance have you not implemented robot karate in a functional way in any Linux distribution? I have been trying in various ways to get the image search engine to recognize them but I have not been able to in any way. manner.

Comment: the answer is - karate robot has not been tested on Linux and native support for windows, buttons etc is not yet done. the image comparison is supposed to work - but will need some real-world testing.